# jbd2/sda3-8 ~ 80% IO activity

Tags: ubuntu

Need help debugging he (very bad) hanging issue with my system.
Its a 12 CPU (thread) system.

iotop shows
about 80% IO against jbd2/sda3-8

top frequently shows
%CPU(s): 20+ wa

However, I also found proc documentation, that explains CPU IO time and that its not reliable.

Comment: So you have some very heavy database activity on your system?

Comment: No. For now, I don't even use database. Most of the use case is for coding though - pycharm, python3 to be specific and filesystem reads. However, if it helps, even when I'm using system for normal browsing or filesystem search etc, it hangs intermittently.